# How do I know if I'm using Excel 2021 or Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Microsoft account has both **Office 365** and **Office 2021** which I bought recently for a new Win 11 PC. When I first installed 2021 and opened Excel I clicked on File, Account and it showed Office 2021.

I had to reset my PC and reinstall Office. I went to Office.com, signed in and clicked the "**Install**" download for the 2021 product just like the first time. The installation says 365 but it said that the first time too. Now when I open Excel and click File, Account it shows Microsoft 365.

When I look in Add or remove programs it shows that I have "Microsoft Office Home and Student 2021-en-us" installed. I opened Excel by typing excel in the search bar. Is there a different way to open Excel to be sure I'm using 2021? Here's the icon and what it looks like:

[image: Icon]

[image: File, Account]

[image: Installed apps]

[image: Blank sheet]

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: After uninstallation have you tried to restart the computer/laptop and then reinstall again. Also what does `About Excel` says? Also one quick check will be to write some where in a cell `TEXTSPLIT()` function which is not present in `Excel 2021` could try these

Comment: You tell by the build number what build number do you have installed?

Comment: If you have an active Office 365 subscription and you log into the Microsoft Account with an active subscription you will inevitably be upgraded to the current Office 365 build even if you originally installed Office 2021.

Comment: Thank you for the replies!  I really appreciate the help.  TEXTSPLIT() works so this must be 365.  I can't find "about" but one of the images above shows the "File, Account" page which I think is similar and it says 365. (thank you Mayukh).  I'm not sure what you mean by build number but in the immediate window I typed "application.version" and it came back as 16.  Is that the build number?  The "File, Account"screen shows Version 2401 (Build 1731.20194 Click-to-Run) so I'm more convinced this is 365 (thanks Ramhound).

Comment: Yikes, Ramhound if this is always true about the upgrade how can I build this PC to have 2021 on it which I need for two reasons: limited number of 365 licenses, and compatibility testing (among other reasons)?  I was pretty sure I had 2021 the first time I installed it.

Comment: Mayukh, I wanted to be sure I did what you suggested so I signed out of Microsoft, uninstalled Office, shut off the PC, restarted, installed Office from the download on my PC.  When I opened it, it clearly was 2021 but said I had to log in to My Microsoft account to activate it to use it.  As soon as I did that, I got a message saying I was being upgraded to 365 features and the info on the File Account page changed to 365.  Ramhound  is right about the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Your version and build number indicates what you're using.

You are using Version 2401 which is the Current Channel release Microsoft 365 Apps (including Excel) of January 30 2024.

Read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date

Screenshot from linked page:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Any suggestions for being able to have my install be the 2021 I purchased instead of 365?

Comment: Try pressing the "Switch license" button

Comment: Thank You, Thank You Thank You!!!!  That worked.  I am very, very, very grateful for your assistance.  Thank you!